# Looping through a generator function that iterates through two very large lists of lists

Tags: python, list, generator

I have 2  very large lists of lists whose sizes are dynamic and not known as they come from a different source and each sublist is **2000** entries long.

I need to iterate through each sublist for both the lists of lists and pass it to sql query, do some data processing and then move on to the next sublist.

Using generators is ideal to iterate through such huge lists of list.

For simplification , I am  recreating the problem by using 2 list of lists that are 10 entries long and each sublist has 2 entries.

```
    def test():
         Send_list= [['2000000000259140093', '1000000000057967562'],
                     ['4000000000008393617', '3000000000006545639'],
                     ['1000000000080880314','1000000000119225203'],
                     ['1000000000096861508', '1000000000254915223'],
                     ['2000000000079125911', '1000000000014797506']]
         Pay_list = [['3000000000020597219', '1000000000079442325'],
                     ['1000000000057621671', '3000000000020542928'],
                     ['3000000000020531804', '4000000000010435913'],
                     ['1000000000330634222', '3000000000002353220'],
                     ['1000000000256385361', '2000000000286618770']]
         for list1,list2 in itertools.izip_longest(Send_list,Pay_list):
               yield [list1,list2]
```

Now , I can use the **next()** function to iterate through piece by piece and pass the sublists to the sql queries.

```
    In [124]: c = next(test())

In [125]: c
Out[125]:
[['2000000000259140093', '1000000000057967562'],
 ['3000000000020597219', '1000000000079442325']]

a = c[0]
b = c[1]
placeholders1 = ','.join('?' for i in range(len(a)))
placeholders2 = ','.join('?' for i in range(len(b)))
sql1 = "select * from Pretty_Txns where Send_Customer in (%s)"% placeholders1
sql2 = "select * from Pretty_Txns where pay_Customer in (%s)"% placeholders2
df_send = pd.read_sql(sql1,cnx,params=a)
df_pay = pd.read_sql(sql2,cnx,params=b)
///data processing and passing the result frame back to sql///
result.to_sql()
///then repeating the same steps for the the next sublists
```

Now when I tried using a for loop to loop through **next()**:

```
   for list in test():
        c = next(test())
        a = c[0]
        b = c[1]
        placeholders1 = ','.join('?' for i in range(len(a)))
        placeholders2 = ','.join('?' for i in range(len(b)))
        sql1 = "select * from Pretty_Txns where Send_Customer in (%s)"% placeholders1
        sql2 = "select * from Pretty_Txns where pay_Customer in (%s)"% placeholders2
        df_send = pd.read_sql(sql1,cnx,params=a)
        df_pay = pd.read_sql(sql2,cnx,params=b)
       ////lot of data processing steps and passing the final results back to sql
        result.to_sql()
```

It only iterates through the first two sublists and does the processing for that and stops.

The value of c right now is:

```
In [145]: c
Out[145]:
[['2000000000259140093', '1000000000057967562'],
 ['3000000000020597219', '1000000000079442325']]
```

This is the first sublist in both **Send_list** and **Pay_list**

```
    In [149]: Send_list
Out[149]:
[['2000000000259140093', '1000000000057967562'],
 ['4000000000008393617', '3000000000006545639'],
 ['1000000000080880314', '1000000000119225203'],
 ['1000000000096861508', '1000000000254915223'],
 ['2000000000079125911', '1000000000014797506']]

In [150]: Pay_list
Out[150]:
[['3000000000020597219', '1000000000079442325'],
 ['1000000000057621671', '3000000000020542928'],
 ['3000000000020531804', '4000000000010435913'],
 ['1000000000330634222', '3000000000002353220'],
 ['1000000000256385361', '2000000000286618770']]
```

Once the data from the **result** dataframe is passed to sql, the control should go back to the step **c=next(test())** and the whole process should repeat until the original list is exhausted.

I am struggling to accomplish that. Looking forward some pointers and guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I don't see why you're mixing a `for` loop with an explicit call to `next`.

Secondly, `next(test())` calls `next` on a *new generator object* at every iteration of the `for` loop, which means `c` will always be the first item from the gen. object. You may need to store the same gen. object somewhere and then call `next` on it repeatedly:

```
gen = test()
c = next(gen)
...
c = next(gen)
```

Finally, `itertools.izip_longest` returns an iterator, so you're probably complicating things by yielding values from it. You can simply return the iterator.

```
def test():
     ...
     return itertools.izip_longest(Send_list, Pay_list):
```

Comment: I cannot be typing c=next(test()) every single time, so I thought of using a for loop.

Comment: @optimus_prime Then the for loop is sufficient. You don't need `next`

Comment: Yes. I figured that out now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well don't create a new generator all the time and only use its first element. Create **one** generator and iterate that.

```
>>> for a, b in test():
        print a, b

['2000000000259140093', '1000000000057967562'] ['3000000000020597219', '1000000000079442325']
['4000000000008393617', '3000000000006545639'] ['1000000000057621671', '3000000000020542928']
['1000000000080880314', '1000000000119225203'] ['3000000000020531804', '4000000000010435913']
['1000000000096861508', '1000000000254915223'] ['1000000000330634222', '3000000000002353220']
['2000000000079125911', '1000000000014797506'] ['1000000000256385361', '2000000000286618770']
```